# Get XmlElement or XmlValue based on attribute type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to parse XML using annotations.

1st XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<something version="1.1" type="Config">
  <section name="General">
    <entry name="calendar" type="calendar">
      <calendar timezone="" datetimepattern="dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss">
        <weekly_rule name="24h">
          <start_time>00:00</start_time>
          <end_time>23:59</end_time>
          <days>SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA</days>
        </weekly_rule>
      </calendar>
    </entry>
  </section>
</something>
```

2nd XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<something version="2.5.3.2" type="Config">
  <section name="General">
    <entry name="BO_1" type="String">Dummy1</entry>
    <entry name="BO_2" type="String">Dummy2</entry>
    <entry name="BO_0" type="String">Dummy3</entry>
  </section>
</something>
```

My problem is with `entry` element. Depending on attribute `type` it should return element (when `type="calendar"`) or value when `type="String"`.

Using Lombok it should be something like this:

```
    @ToString
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Entry {

        @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
        private String name;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
        private String type;
        @XmlValue
        private String text;
        private Object calendar;

    }
```

But it does not work because there cannot be value and element at once. How to do this using annotations?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to return one or another property
depending on an XML attribute.

But as a partial solution to problem,
you can model the mixed content between `<entry ...>` and `</entry>`
by using a combination of [`@XmlMixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlMixed.html) and [`@XmlElementRef`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html)
on a `List<Object>` property in your `Entry` class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlElementRef(name = "calendar", type = Calendar.class)
    private List<Object> mixedContent;
}
```

You also need to annotate your `Calendar` class
with `@XmlRootElement(name="calendar"`).

During unmarshalling of an XML element `<entry ...>...</entry>`
the `List<Object> mixedContent` is filled with
a mixture of `String` and `Calendar` objects.

For example:

- For XML input

  ```
  <entry name="BO_1" type="String">Dummy1</entry>
  ```

  the `List<Object> mixedContent` will contain just one object:
  the string `"Dummy1"`.
- For XML input

  ```
  <entry name="calendar" type="calendar">
      <calendar ...>
        ...
      </calendar>
  </entry>
  ```

  the `List<Object> mixedContent` will contain 3 objects:
  the string `"\n    "`, a `Calendar` object, the string `"\n    "`.

For easier getting of the interesting element in `mixedContent`,
dependent on the `type` attribute,
you may add the following method to your `Entry` class.

```
public Object getContent() {
    if (type.equals("String")) {
        for (Object obj : mixedContent) {
            if (obj instanceof String)
                return obj;
        }
    }
    if (type.equals("calendar")) {
        for (Object obj : mixedContent) {
            if (obj instanceof Calendar)
                return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```